# bind dynamic input fields to bean class spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a form in-which I  add dynamic  input fields to the form, how can I bind these dynamic input values to the list (Java.lang.Util)variable which is inside the bean class.

My Form:

[image: My Form with dynamic options]

```
    public class CQuestion {    
    private String question;
    private List<COption> COptions;
    public CQuestion() {
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public List<COption> getCOptions() {
        return this.COptions;
    }
    public void setCOptions(List<COption> COptions) {
        this.COptions = COptions;
    }
    public COption addCOption(COption COption) {
        getCOptions().add(COption);
        COption.setCQuestion(this);
        return COption;
    }
    public COption removeCOption(COption COption) {
        getCOptions().remove(COption);
        COption.setCQuestion(null);
        return COption;
    }
    }
```

COption.java bean class

```
public class COption {  

    private String option;  
    private String explanation; 
    private boolean isCorrect;

    public COption() {
    }   

    public String getOption() {
        return this.option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return isCorrect;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean isCorrect) {
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
    }

    public String getExplanation() {
        return explanation;
    }

    public void setExplanation(String explanation) {
        this.explanation = explanation;
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
public @ResponseBody String add(@ModelAttribute CQuestion question,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {
}
```

Using the above code , I am getting only the question value not the option values(java.lang.util.List). Can you suggest me a way to bind these dynamic options with bean class?

Comment: im having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing ajax post. If that is the case, you can something similar.

```
var options= new Array();
options.push("option1"); // these are values from your dynamic fields
options.push("option2");
$.ajax({
        url: "/add",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {COptions:options},
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I want to bind values of option,isCorrect, Explanation into the list of COption object inside CQuestion object.

Comment: Could not understand your comment. data: {COptions:options}, should bind to your list inside model attribute CQuestion.

Comment: It is not binding.. I am using form.serialize() function from Jquery.

Comment: Show me your HTML with dynamic values simulated into it and your form submit.

Comment: i will post the html  with dynamic values in 10 minutes.... I came across this link, http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/
I think , It will also help in solving this.. Do you have any idea on this ?.. Again I am not using spring form-tags library, I am using basic bootstrap form inside the modal..

Comment: Please have a look at the application which is  deployed on the ec2 instance. http://ec2-52-10-55-149.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/certifier-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/tests/1

Username:admin
Password:admin

Comment: I could not see anything up there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71140/discussion-between-vel-and-minion).